# I have three activities.From the main activity i can call the 2nd, but i can't call the 3rd one?

Tags: android, android-activity, manifest, multiscreen

In this app i designed 3 activities. 
from the 1st activity i have 2 buttons for 
the other 2 activities respectively add and view.
the add activity is executed but the view is not working.
 Thanks for any helps..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.task.reminder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.task.reminder.TaskActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".View"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >>
                          </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Add"
             android:label="@string/app_name" >>
                        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas...

Comment: is it a copy/paste error that your two last activities finish with ">>" ?

Comment: ya..this is a mistake by copy.

Comment: ok. are your View and Add Activity in the 'com.task.reminder' package?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `View`  and `Add` Activity declaration in manifest as:

```
<activity android:name=".View"
     android:label="@string/app_name" />

<activity android:name=".Add"
     android:label="@string/app_name"/>
```

**NOTE :** View is already a class in Android so maybe this name will cause problem when you use Intent for starting View.java Activity. you can also change name of  View.java  Activity

you will also see :

[Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Comment: @AndRaGhu : plz post relevant code and logcat result if it's crashing

Comment: @AndRaGhu : have you try it by changing name of View Activity?

Comment: I got it,After changed the view activity name.

Comment: And i have another one dought, In my system the i can't use the datepicker widget, it shows                                                    "The following classes could not be found:
- CalendarView (Change to android.widget.CalendarView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- DatePicker (Change to android.widget.DatePicker, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
"

Comment: @AndRaGhu : means i'm not getting you so plz make me clear what u want to say about datepicker widget

Comment: I can't use datepicker component in my design.

Comment: I just now trying to design a task remainder app.so i need that,

Comment: means you want to use datepicker in your application ?

Comment: @AndRaGhu : you can see http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/ tutorial about datepicker in android and if you have any issue in implementing it in your application then post it as new question here.thanks so much if this answer help u u can mark it as answer or upvote it.